# validation_errors codeigniter function displaying fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to form validation with codeigniter, I thoroughly followed the tutorial on the CI site but I seem to keep getting an error.

Here's my View (solicitar.php):

```
<?php 
          echo validation_errors(); 
          ?>

          <?php 
          echo form_open('main/form'); 
          ?>

          <fieldset>
          <label class="name">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
          </label>

          <label class="email">
          <input type="text"  id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
          </label>

          <label class="phone">
          <input type="text" id="tele" name="tele" placeholder="Telefono">
          </label>

          <label class="email">
          <input type="text" id="taller" name="taller" value="<?=str_replace('_', ' ', $taller)?>" readonly>
          </label>

          <label class="message">
          <textarea name="texto" id="texto" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
          </label>

          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">

          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

This is my Controller (main):

```
public function form()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('solicitar');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
```

The validation_errors() function is not working. It outputs:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors()
```

I can't see what I am missing.

Comment: Try setting a couple of rules for it to check against.

Comment: which function loading your `solicitar.php` except form function.You also need to load the `form_validation` there.better load the library inside your construct of the controller.

Comment: I loaded it from the construct and it worked! Thanks, But what difference does it make? For a second I thought my error lied on the fact that I didn't create a new controller just to validate.

Answer (score 0):

in your view file you have this

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

but you had not loaded the form_validation library so you got the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors()
```

so PHP was looking for the function validation_errors() but couldn't find it.

Then when you added load form_validation to your constructor -- it loaded it before calling the view file -- PHP found the function -- thus no error.